# How to debug an error with python script with no traceback errors?

Tags: python, shell

```
def make_offsite_copies_primary():
    """multi-threaded function to update OFFSITE_PREFIX volumes to primary."""

    start_date = time.strftime("%m/%d/%y",
                           time.localtime(time.time() - DR_TAPE_DATE_RANGE))

    for pool in run_command([vmpool, "-listall", "-b"]).readlines():
        if pool.startswith(OFFSITE_PREFIX):
            pool = pool.split()[0]
            logentry("***\tupdating images for pool: %s" % (pool))
            command = [bpchangeprimary, "-pool", pool, "-sd", start_date]
            RunMTCommand.lck.acquire()
            # If we've reached maxthreads, then wait for one to finish
            if len(RunMTCommand.tlist) >= RunMTCommand.maxthreads:
                RunMTCommand.lck.release()
                RunMTCommand.evnt.wait()
            else:
                RunMTCommand.lck.release()
            # For some reason, we often get a "-15" RC, when updating the
            # MLC-Duplication pool.  Let's just ignore it for now.
            RunMTCommand.newthread(command, [0, 13, -15])

    for bpchange_thread in RunMTCommand.tlist:
        bpchange_thread.join()
```

This function issues a NetBackup command to promote a copy of a backup to be the primary copy.

When this script is run, it starts logging in the terminal as expected:

```
Mon Aug 24 10:04:08 2015 - 17684 - ***  updating images for pool: MLC-2week
Mon Aug 24 10:04:08 2015 - 17684 - ***  updating images for pool: MLC-1month
Mon Aug 24 10:04:08 2015 - 17684 - ***  updating images for pool: MLC-1year
Mon Aug 24 10:04:08 2015 - 17684 - ***  updating images for pool: MLC-Shadow-2week
Mon Aug 24 10:04:08 2015 - 17684 - ***  updating images for pool: MLC-2week-DR-Files
Mon Aug 24 10:04:08 2015 - 17684 - ***  updating images for pool: MLC-Offsite

etc.
```

However, the bpchangeprimary command does not seem to be called within the script because the backup copies do not change.

If you type 'bpchangeprimary -pool MLC-LTO4-Offsite -sd 08/22/2015' directly from the command line, this makes the intended changes to the backup copies.  However, this line inside the function:

```
command = [bpchangeprimary, "-pool", pool, "-sd", start_date]
```

Should accomplish the same thing, but it's not, so I'm guessing something is wrong with this function.  To make things worse, there are no traceback errors.

Any help, or tips on how to troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using pdb (or ipdb)?

Comment: In your `RunMTCommand` class, log what the subprocess puts through the STDOUT and STDERR pipes.

Comment: What do you mean the subprocess?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `command = [bpchangeprimary, "-pool", pool, "-sd", start_date]` just prepares the command to be executed, it doesn't actually execute it.

Your `logentry()` call in its current position is therefore producing misleading log entries.

The command execution is only attempted at/after this call:

```
RunMTCommand.newthread(command, [0, 13, -15])
```

I'd start with moving your `logentry()` call (or adjusting its content and adding a new one) further down, below the `if... then... else...` logic meant to limit the number of threads - to first get meaningfull logging.

This should tell at least if the execution goes past the thread limiting logic:

- if it doesn't then you need to debug that logic
- if it does then focus on the thread starting in the multithread context and/or actual command execution

Comment: Is it worth trying to just remove all of the threading stuff from this function?

Comment: What is frustrating is that there is no test environment for me to mess around in, if I remove the threading or alter this function and run the script, it could potentially cause damage.

Comment: Are you saying to move the log entry line to the bottom of the function?

Comment: Between the `if... then... else...` and `RunMTCommand.newthread(...)`

Comment: It did not go past the thread limiting logic, so I am trying to remove all the threading from this function.  Is the only downside to removing the threading is just that the function will take longer to run?

Comment: Normally yes, threading is typically used to increase performance by running things in parallel. Droping threading simplifies things (everything runs serially, no need for thread control, synchronisation, mutexes, etc) at the expense of performance. But in unfamilar code it might not be trivial to drop threading because of the no longer necessary code which often needs to be removed as well as it may negatively interfere with the now serialized operation, it *might* be simpler just to debug and fix threading instead. Choose whichever you feel more comfortable with.